# Scapy traffic generator for DPDK L3FWD application

Tags: linux, scapy, dpdk

I am new to DPDK and trying to run L3FWD app using scapy to send traffic to it.

I have two Hosts. Host A(Ubuntu 4.15.0-154-generic) for Scapy to send the traffic. Host B (Ubuntu 5.11.0-25-generic) for DPDK(21.08.0) and Host B has vfio-pci module and two NICs (Ethernet Controller XXV710) binded to it.

I have huge pages inserted like below

```
mkdir -p /dev/hugepages
  mountpoint -q /dev/hugepages || mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /dev/hugepages
  echo 1024 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
  echo 1024 > /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
```

I verified the connectivity between Hosts using Scapy on Host A and tcpdump on Host B. (Traffic is coming in from Host A to B)

I build the DPDK and its example apps. I am trying to run L3FWD with this arguments on Host B.

```
./dpdk-l3fwd -l 1,2 -n 4 -- -p 0x3 --config="(0,0,1),(1,0,2)"
```

And I tried many ways of sending the traffic from Host A to B using Scapy like below and still not able to see the output of L3FWD on Host B.

way 1)

```
sendp(Ether()/IP(src="1X.1X.2x.1x"), iface="enp25s0f0",count=1000)
```

using sendp command, I didn't see traffic on Host B with L3FWD running. Please note, for src ip add i have replaced numeric values with x here

way 2)

```
send(IP(src="1x.1x.2x.1x"), iface="enp25s0f0",count=1000)
```

using send command, I didn't see traffic on Host B with L3FWD running

way 3)>>

```
x = Ether(src='xc:xd:xe:a9:x9:x0', dst='xC:xx:xx:Ax:Bx:x1')   
sendp(x, iface='enp25s0f0',count=10000)
```

This also didn't work

pls Note I have replaced above actual MAC and IP addr with few 'x'.

Output of L3FWD is as below

```
./build/examples/dpdk-l3fwd -l 1,2 -n 4 -- -p 0x3 --config="(0,0,1),(1,0,2)"
EAL: Detected 56 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
**EAL: No available 1048576 kB hugepages reported**
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Using IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_i40e (8086:158b) device: 0000:18:00.0 (socket 0)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_i40e (8086:158b) device: 0000:18:00.1 (socket 0)
**TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created**
Neither LPM, EM, or FIB selected, defaulting to LPM
Initializing port 0 ... Creating queues: nb_rxq=1 nb_txq=2... Port 0 modified RSS hash function based on hardware support,requested:0xa38c configured:0x2288
 Address:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, Destination:02:00:00:00:00:00, Allocated mbuf pool on socket 0
LPM: Adding route 198.18.0.0 / 24 (0)
LPM: Adding route 198.18.1.0 / 24 (1)
LPM: Adding route 2001:200:: / 64 (0)
LPM: Adding route 2001:200:0:1:: / 64 (1)
txq=1,0,0 txq=2,1,0
Initializing port 1 ... Creating queues: nb_rxq=1 nb_txq=2... Port 1 modified RSS hash function based on hardware support,requested:0xa38c configured:0x2288
 Address:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, Destination:02:00:00:00:00:01, txq=1,0,0 txq=2,1,0

Initializing rx queues on lcore 1 ... rxq=0,0,0
Initializing rx queues on lcore 2 ... rxq=1,0,0

Checking link status........done
Port 0 Link up at 25 Gbps FDX Autoneg
Port 1 Link up at 25 Gbps FDX Autoneg
L3FWD: entering main loop on lcore 1
L3FWD:  -- lcoreid=1 portid=0 rxqueueid=0
L3FWD: entering main loop on lcore 2
L3FWD:  -- lcoreid=2 portid=1 rxqueueid=0
```

Output of L3FWD doesn't go forward after this point.

Can any of you please help me find out where i am going wrong. Or help me know how to send traffic  from Host A to run L3FWD app on Host B.
Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Hi, I added -P as ** ./build/examples/dpdk-l3fwd -l 1,2 -n 4 -- -p 0x3 -P --config="(0,0,1),(1,0,2)" ** and output doesn't go forward, its same as output i pasted above. Thanks

Comment: I am new to this and trying to explore the dpdk sample apps. I am able to run L2FWD app and see traffic statistics coming in from Host A to B. So the connection is good. I am just curious to see the output of L3FWD. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah as u said, I am able to see the packets on other port of Host A using tcpdump. I see  "901558 LLDP, length 69" printing. That concludes that packets are forwarded between ports right. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @VinayGowda I think there are 2 things you should do `1) use dpdk-procinfo dor stats gather rx-tx and 2) from scapy send packet matching to rule that is 198.18.0.0`

Comment: are there any  updates from you end @VinayGowda?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] the solution mentioned in the answer is tried and tested on both HOST and Virtual machines and it works.

There are a couple of ways to check if L3fwd is actually receiving and sending the matches rule traffic. One can check the statistics

1. using DPDK secondary application `dpdk-procinfo` for DPDK ports
2. checking the statistics at the HOST-B PF port via `ethtool`
3. checking stats at the sender (scapy) on Host-A

For your specific use cases there 2 factors to match

1. Since DPDK ports on Host-B is created via VF over single PF interface, you would at least have to send packets with VF-1 MAC address to allow the packet to be received in.
2. For packets to send out from VF-2, the mac address of the packet has to be modified to allow be forwarded out from Host-B PF to Host-A.

Note: If you were having 2 separate PF NIC on Host-B one need to configure ports on Host-A to promiscuous mode to receive with any MAC address.

Solution:

1. Program Scapy to send ETH-IP packet with MAC address of VF-1 (assuming MAC-VLAN is not enabled on PF) and Dest IP Address of LPM table entry as `198.18.X.X` (where X stands for wild card byte value)
2. check with the dpdk secondary application for Port-0 (VF-1) and Port-1 (VF-2) to confirm packets are indeed received and transmitted out.
3. Check on Host-B statistics of PF using `cat /proc/net/dev` to see if packets are received, transmitted or dropped.

Note: the sample program can be easily edited with print and rte_pktmbuf_dump too.