# What is the correct way to run the l3fwd example in DPDK?

Tags: dpdk, dpdk-pmd

I'm going through the DPDK examples and I'm having trouble running it properly, in this case I'm trying to run the l3fwd examples, I started with the basic **dpdk-l3fwd**.

[DPDK Documentation:l3_forward](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/l3_forward.html)

I'm building DPDK from source
DPDK version: **20.05** 
NICs: Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27800 Family [**ConnectX-5** Virtual Function] 
SSHADDR= PCI address for the card I'm using to ssh (since I don't want to lose connectivity) 
I have set up Hugepages already.

I initially started using the same cmdline arguments as:
[Scapy traffic generator for DPDK L3FWD application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836518/scapy-traffic-generator-for-dpdk-l3fwd-application)
(but no issue is reported on their side).

`./dpdk-l3fwd -b $SSHADDR -l 1,2 -n 4 -- -p 0x3 --config="(0,0,1),(1,0,2)"`  
but even trying something simpler does not work for me: 
`./dpdk-l3fwd  -b $SSHADDR -l 1 -n 1 -- -p 0x1 --config="(0,0,1)"`  
I keep getting the error message:

```
Initializing rx queues on lcore 1 ... rxq=0,0,0 Invalid RX queue_id=0
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: rte_eth_rx_queue_setup: err=-22, port=0
```

This is coming from `rte_eth_rx_queue_setup` in `rte_ethdev.c`, which is reporting that `dev->data->nb_rx_queues = 0` , hence why the the error says Invalid RX queue. So it seems like the device itself does not support any rx queues, however, running testpmd (which calls the same function and sets up the rx_queues) is successful, which makes this really confusing.

What am I doing wrong?

Full output:

```
./dpdk-l3fwd  -b $SSHADDR -l 1 -n 1 -- -p 0x1 --config="(0,0,1)"
EAL: Detected 16 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: 1 hugepages of size 1073741824 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found for that size
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_mlx5 (15b3:1018) device: XXXX:00:02.0 (socket 0)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_mlx5 (15b3:1018) device: XXXX:00:02.0 (socket 0)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_mlx5 (15b3:1018) device: XXXX:00:02.0 (socket 0)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_mlx5 (15b3:1018) device: XXXX:00:02.0 (socket 0)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_mlx5 (15b3:1018) device: XXXX:00:02.0 (socket 0)
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Cannot delete qdisc with handle of zero
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Cannot delete qdisc with handle of zero
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
tap_nl_dump_ext_ack(): Failed to find qdisc with specified classid
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
LPM or EM none selected, default LPM on

Skipping disabled port 1

Skipping disabled port 2

Skipping disabled port 4

Skipping disabled port 5

Skipping disabled port 7

Initializing rx queues on lcore 1 ... rxq=0,0,0 Invalid RX queue_id=0
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: rte_eth_rx_queue_setup: err=-22, port=0
```

Comment: You have mentioned `MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5 Virtual Function]` as virtual function, is this interface `up`? can you check with `ethtool` or `mlxconfig` about the status of the device and how many rx queue are assigned. Because `Cause: rte_eth_rx_queue_setup: err=-22, port=` on mellanox occurs when the PF or VF is not ready from kernel netdev. Also `tap_nl_dump_ext_ack` is for tap interface `TAP PMD`. hence please re-run your application with `--log-level=pmd,8` real option to understand better.

Comment: @VipinVarghese thanks for the pointers!, I agree it seems to me that such device is unable to setup any queues, again the weird thing was that `testpmd` had no trouble performing the same task.
Sadly I rebooted the device and things just started working fine, I'm unable to get back to the old state to debug further. Thanks!